# How to read a text file from server using JavaScript with complete path?

Tags: javascript

I want load a remote file from a server.

This file is not in a web site. So when I open a file I use

```
window.open('http://5.135.140.184:8080/tpi/documents/D773.JPG', '_blank');
```

This opens my picture. But if I want to use a complete path, I use

```
window.open("http://5.135.140.184:8080/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/tpi/documents/D773.JPG", '_blank');
```

In this case I have a 404 error ... How do I do?

P.S.The file `D773.JPG` is in the path `var/lib/tomcat/webapps/tpi/documents`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I'm afraid your question is unclear and contradicts itself. You said "This file is not in a web sites" (sic) but then you said you can access the file via `http://5.135.140.184:8080/tpi/documents/D773.JPG`, which means it *is* in a web site. Which is it?

Comment: I want load an other file that is not in the web sites...

Comment: You can't, via HTTP.

Comment: There's no need to SHOUT.

Comment: different things can happen here, some inconsistencies in the question can make us think that you're trying to access a file that is not accessible (in a computer without server or something likely). If we ignore some of the contradicting points, it can also be that you have a confusion between the server folder directory and what's accessible through an URL (in your case, what's in the folders `var/lib/tomcat/webapps/tpi/documents` would not be accessible through this exact path by URL, but by `tpi/documents`). There can be redirecting rules that can affect an URL destination too

Comment: To summarise Kadath's point: don't assume that the path to the file on disk is the same as the path to it which is accessible through the webserver.

Comment: If I use window.open('ftp: //5.135.140.184/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/tpi/documents/D773.JPG', '_blank'); ?

Comment: how do I do, help me?

Comment: `If I use window.open('ftp: //5.135.140.184/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/tpi/documents/D773.JPG', '_blank'); ?` ...that's not a question. What do you mean? If you do that then...what? Why do you think using FTP is going to be any better than HTTP?

Comment: Yes...if i use ftp, can  I view the remote file?Now, i have not a password  to do the test

Comment: Only if FTP is running and configured such that the file is accessible at that URL. Having an FTP server is no different (in that particular respect) to having a HTTP server running. It's not magic, you have to set it up. Also it's an insecure and legacy tech, I wouldn't recommend it. Just set up your HTTP server correctly to be able to reach the location on disk that you need, or serve the file from a location which _is_ accessible already by HTTP.

Comment: Also, to go back to the start, in the question you actually said "So when I open a file I use

`window.open('http://5.135.140.184:8080/tpi/documents/D773.JPG'`, '_blank'); 
This opens my picture"...so if it opens it successfully, what's the problem? Sounds like your server is configured to serve files from `var/lib/tomcat/webapps/tpi/documents` but exposes `tpi/documents` as the root of the website. That's quite usual. If you want to serve files from elsewhere, change the config, you can usually have multiple "virtual" directories that files can be served from, from different places on disk

Comment: How  set up my HTTP server correctly to be able to reach the location on disk that I need?

Comment: How do I do to  have multiple "virtual" directories that files can be served from different places on disk

Comment: did you consult the manual? I assume your server is Tomcat, it will have documentation online. And probably there are many answers on SO and other sites previously relating to this. Personally I haven't got direct experience with Tomcat, but others may have. Make an attempt. If you can't figure it out, ask a new question tagged with tomcat and show what you've done.

Answer (score 3):

You can only access things via HTTP that are served by an HTTP (e.g., "web") server which recognizes and handles the URL you give it. It would be possible to configure an HTTP server to allow you to access any file by full path, but it would almost certainly be an extraordinarily bad idea to make **all* files on a machine accessible via HTTP.

Your question contradicts itself by saying both that the file isn't in a web site and that you can access the file via `http://5.135.140.184:8080/tpi/documents/D773.JPG`. If you can access the file via that URL, then an HTTP server at `5.135.140.184:8080` is running and handles that URL by giving you the file. That's what you should stick with.

In a comment you've added

> I want load an other file that is not in the web sites.

You can't, not via HTTP. HTTP requires a web server that understands the URL. If your web server at `5.135.140.184:8080` isn't configured to deliver the file you want, you cannot access it via HTTP (without changing the server configuration).

Comment: Was just typing something similar. +1

Since `http://5.135.140.184:8080/var/lib/tomcat/webapps` is serving a web directory hence you receive the file via `http://5.135.140.184:8080/tpi/documents/D773.JPG`

Comment: If I use  window.open('ftp: //5.135.140.184/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/tpi/documents/D773.JPG', '_blank'); ?

Comment: If you have an FTP server set up to expose all of your files via FTP (a **Bad Idea™**), sure. Or if you have it set up to do file sharing of all your files (a **Bad Idea™**), you could use a `file:///` URL.